# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't boot from usb

Tags: 12.10, usb, unetbootin

So I want to switch from Linux Mint 15 to Ubuntu 12.10. I used UNetBootin to create the usb. I have Linux Mint 15, and am trying to get Ubuntu to load from the usb. But when I restart my computer it says "Boot Error." I haven't tested it on another computer yet. Any ideas?

-EDIT: What I expected to happen was Ubuntu would boot up instead of giving the "Boot Error" message. What I did was just formatting and formatting over and over again due to it saying the same thing(Boot Error). I'm using a Kingston 4GB usb drive. I also tried a 16GB drive but I don't know the name.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had good luck with unetbootin recently either. You might try `dd` from the command:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

dd will wipe the 'output file' with great efficiency, so don't mess up and point it at the wrong destination. You'll want to make sure you're target USB is `/dev/sbd`.

Comment: It says no such file or directory.

Comment: Also I'm very new to linux so I dont know this dd stuff. It's an ancient language to me.

Comment: `sudo` means 'superuser do' and is required to manke any system-wide changes.

`dd` is a direct byte by byte copy utility and more. More dangerouse if you switch the destination and source.

`if` tells dd what and where the input file is.

`of` tells dd where the output file sould be written.

`/dev/sbd` is` where the USB drive that is to be completely overwritten is located. This might be different, depending on what you have plggued in to your USB ports.